# How to install numpy on mingw64 python on Windows?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pip, mingw-w64

I am able to successfully install numpy [using pacman package](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-python-numpy) on mingw64 on Windows OS.
But, when I try to install via pip, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
Failed to build numpy
ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Installed python and pip details :

```
pip version 23.1.2 from C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)
Python 3.10.11 [GCC 12.2.0 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

Comment: The error output you've listed is just information that the wheel build failed, but contains no indication as to why. There might be a good hint on the console, but beyond that and as is, there is really no way to tell beyond: well, that didn't work as hoped. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @OndrejK. here is console error output : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xxmbh4CzY1X7gKQSGV4jZ8ObxL922D_7/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: @SwaminathBera no one is going to click an extra link just to see your error output. use the [edit] function and add it to your question using appropriate formatting